# Typescript error "Expected 1 type arguments" showing on one machine but not the other

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I get the following typescript error on one of my laptops but not the other. Both are using the latest version of vscode and typescript. I've deleted my local repo on both machines and made a fresh clone but the error persists on one machine.

This is the error:

[image]

[image]

According to [this example](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) on the styled-component docs, my code is correct. `styled<>` should take 2 arguments:

```
import styled from "app/styled-components"

// theme is now fully typed
const Title = styled<{ isActive: boolean }, "h1">("h1")`
  color: ${props => props.isActive ? props.theme.primaryColor : props.theme.secondaryColor}
`
```

I don't know why this Typescript error is showing up on only one machine. Any advice on how to troubleshoot this error further would be appreciated. Thanks.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fb-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "firebase": "^5.5.7",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lorem-ipsum": "^1.0.6",
    "material-ui-flat-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "mathjs": "^5.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-easy-state": "^6.0.5",
    "react-responsive": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.0",
    "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
    "react-string-replace": "^0.4.1",
    "react-window-size": "^1.2.2",
    "shortid": "^2.2.13",
    "styled-components": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,json,css,md}'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.117",
    "@types/mathjs": "^4.4.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
    "@types/react-responsive": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/shortid": "0.0.29",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.0.3",
    "husky": "^1.1.3",
    "lint-staged": "^8.0.4",
    "prettier": "1.15.3",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx,json,css,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting different errors, the `tsc` compiler is likely using a different set of typings on each machine for some reason.  Maybe different versions of npm got different transitive dependencies, or something like that.  You should run `tsc --traceResolution`, which will be quite verbose, but you can search in the output to find out exactly what `.d.ts` file it detected for the `styled` type's typings.  This is your starting point, which is to determine what files are providing the typings to the compiler, then work backwards to find out how you ended up with different versions.